# Using style='' inside boostrap tooltip

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've got the follwing HTML:

```
<a href="#" title="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-original-title="1 bookmark<br/>Category: <span style=&quot;color: #FF9AA2&quot;>Red</span>" aria-describedby="tooltip92967">My Tooltip Demo</a>
```

The bootstrap tooltip display correctly, apart from the color of the span changing to red.  How can I style the span so that it applies the color inside the tool tip? All the text is the standard white of the bootstrap tooltips.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below where you set the color as data attribute of the link element.

```js
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})

$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').on('inserted.bs.tooltip', function () {
  var c = $(this).data("color");
  $('.tooltip span').css('color',c);
})
```

```css
a {
 margin:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-6khuMg9gaYr5AxOqhkVIODVIvm9ynTT5J4V1cfthmT+emCG6yVmEZsRHdxlotUnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<a href="#" title="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-original-title="1 bookmark<br/>Category: <span >Red</span>" data-color='#FF9AA2' aria-describedby="tooltip92967">My Tooltip Demo</a>

<a href="#" title="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-original-title="1 bookmark<br/>Category: <span >green</span>" data-color='#00FF22' aria-describedby="tooltip92967">another Tooltip Demo</a>
```

Reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/tooltips/#events

Comment: Unfortunately that won't help as I need to set the span colour on the fly for each href.

Comment: @Chud37 the color is set *for each* href

Comment: Oh i see, sorry I didn't the whole answer on my mobile. I'll give it a go.